# Urllib returns 'No such file or directory error'

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to access a certain 'third-party' database via a URL, using the `urllib.request` library but I get this error instead:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory>
```

I have been able to access the link several times with the same script some time before though.

```
import urllib.request

def read_temp():
    url = "https://maturity.000webhostapp.com/api/temp/read_all.php"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    json_obj = str(response, 'utf-8')
    data = json.loads(json_obj)
```

I'd expected that the script should work effortlessly but sometimes it fails to connect.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Link gives: `HTTP Error 410: Gone`.

Comment: Are there other reliable web severs that can function as such; a friend mentioned 'firebase' some time ago?

Answer (score 1):

The website has been taken down by the owner.

[image]